# Trying to catch a failed allocation inside of a recursive function: Unhandled exception/Stack overflow

Tags: c++, list, exception, recursion, allocation

This is a problem I'm trying to solve for a school assignment. I've created a single linked list class that contains a Node(ie. a struct that holds a character "item", and a Node pointer "next") and a Node pointer head. As specified by the assignment, I'm required to implement several operations on the linked list recursively. I've managed to get all of this working fine.

However, as the next step of the assignment I'm asked to: *"write a test program to determine what the longest possible linked list is. (You will be testing the heap size). You can do this easily since the append function is defined to return true if successful and false otherwise."*

In class, it was mentioned that we should use something along the lines of

```
try{ //Allocate a new node
     // Throw an exception if it fails
}
catch(...){
     // Do something with the caught exception
}
```

And for the life of me, I can't get this to work! I'm getting the following error:

`Unhandled exception at 0x7765DED4 (ntdll.dll) in Assignment.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00352FFC).`

This is my first time dealing with exceptions, so maybe I'm missing something, but I've been trawling google and my collection of textbooks for hours and I'm officially stuck.

Here is the code in question:

```
// RECURSIVELY appends an element to the end of the list
bool LinkedList::append(char newChar){ 
    if (head == nullptr){ // Adds a node to empty list
        head = new Node{ newChar, nullptr };
        return true;
    }
    return appendHelper(newChar, head); // Call the recursive helper function
}

// Helper function for append
bool LinkedList::appendHelper(char newChar, Node* currentNode){     
    if (currentNode->next == nullptr){ // Adds a node to the end of a list

        // HERE'S WHERE THE TROUBLE BEGINS:
        try{
            currentNode->next = new Node{ newChar, nullptr }; // From what I've read, this should throw std::bad_alloc if it fails?
        }
        catch(...){ // The "..." should catch ANY exception, right?
            return false; // Return false, so that I'll know allocation failed
        }
        return true; // Mustn't have encountered an exception; return true.
    }
    return appendHelper(newChar, currentNode->next);
}
```

I'm fairly confident that my code, aside from the exception handling, works. Ie. Adding a node using:

```
currentNode->next = new Node{ newChar, nullptr };
```

seems to work fine. The discussion we had in class left me with the impression that I should be able to catch the exception when the allocation fails, return a false, then continue with the rest of my program/experiement...

Any idea where am I going wrong, or how can I solve this? I'm starting to think that I should just iterate a counter and print it to the screen every time I call the `append()` function, then just record this number when it crashes... But this doesn't seem very elegant, nor do I feel that this is what was expected.

Comment: Unless your compiler is optimizing tail-recursion, it's more likely that you'll be testing the stack size than the heap size here.

Comment: Maybe that's just a typo... Does it change the question significantly?

Comment: It kinda depends.  When you say you "can't get it to work", what do you mean?  Is your program crashing (with a stack overflow), or does it work fine?  The complexity of calling `append` as you have written it will cause your program to take a VERY long time to exhaust the heap, because it has exponential time complexity.  To do it in linear time, you need your list to keep track of the last node (rather than searching every time), OR you can insert new nodes at the head.  For more help, please be more specific about what is happening.  There's also a non-throwing version of `new`, by the way.

Comment: Oh crap, I guess I should have included that in the original question (sorry).

I've updated the main question but since you asked, I'm getting: 

Unhandled exception at 0x7765DED4 (ntdll.dll) in Assignment.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00352FFC).

Comment: Are you sure you're meant to use recursion? This is not really anything to do with try/catch or bad_alloc, it's is a stack overflow (i.e. too many nested calls). Also note that what Windows calls an "exception" isn't the same as what C++ calls an "exception"

Comment: Right, so a stack overflow would indicate that your compiler is _not_ doing tail-recursive optimisations and you are running out of stack space.  This is not an exception you can catch.  You could try doing a Release build with full optimisations, but rather than relying on tail-recursion are you sure you are required to implement `append` recursively?  You can still use my suggestion of inserting at the head or remembering the tail node.

Comment: immibis - Yes, the assignment specifically requires me to use recursion for this part, but your answer is very interesting and has got me thinking... 

I didn't realize that a windows exception and c++ exception weren't the same thing! What's the difference?

Also, out of curiosity, why is a stack overflow uncatchable?

Why is an allocation error with an iterative function able to throw an exception and continue, whereas recursion breaks everything? (I'm guessing it's obviously to do with memory...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to distinguish between two kinds of exceptions: **hardware exception** and **software exception**. C++ exception can be considered as a software exception, so using C++ try/catch statement you can catch only software exceptions. An example of software exceptions is when program detects that invalid parameter has been specified for some procedure.

Hardware exceptions are far more serious and are thrown by CPU itself. Example of hardware exception are: division by zero, trying to access an invalid memory address, **stack overflow** and others. Many of these hardware exceptions are handled by operating system itself (debuggers also process some of these exceptions) and it is **strongly recommended** not to catch these exceptions in your program. Doing so you might prevent lower level systems to properly ***clean-up*** the mess that was left behind.

So back to stack overflow that you're having trouble with, when this hardware exception happens the stack pointer has exceeded the stack bound. In other words, your program is out of stack (this is over-simplification because each thread in the process gets certain amount of stack space so it might be that only thread ran out of stack). Even if you would handle this exception what would you like to do? You are out of stack so your options are very limited (for example even defining a local variable, or calling a function will probably cause another exception).

This is why program shouldn't handle such exceptions - at the application level, you just don't have enough wisdom to properly recover, while OS is able to clean up the mess your app produced.

That being said, Windows allows you to catch such exceptions... ***Structured Exception Handling*** can be used to catch both hardware and software exceptions on Windows. But, if you're wise programmer, you probably won't do this.

[Structured Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx)

[More on hardware exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w49wew4f.aspx)